# Java para calcular precio de receta

Tags: java

Como funcionaria un programa para hacer arroz con marisco. Sabiendo que cada persona necesita 125gr de arroz, 50 gramos de mejillones y 100 de pescado. El programa preguntaria el precio kg de cada ingrediente y para cuanta gente se va a preparar el plato. El programa proporcionara la cantidad necesaria de cada ingrediente, el precio por persona y el precio total.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fidegua {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Float> price = new ArrayList<Float>();
       
       
        System.out.println("Para cuantas personas vas a cocinar?");
        int people=sc.nextInt();
        
            System.out.print("Precio del arroz [€/kg]: ");
            final float pricePerWeight = sc.nextFloat();
            price.add(pricePerWeight);
            if (pricePerWeight <= 0) {
              
            
            }
            
            System.out.print("Precio de las gambas [€/kg]: ");
            final float pricePerWeight1 = sc.nextFloat();
            price.add(pricePerWeight1);
            if (pricePerWeight1 <= 0) {
              
            
            }
            
            System.out.print("Precio de los calamares [€/kg]: ");
            final float pricePerWeight2 = sc.nextFloat();
            price.add(pricePerWeight2);
            if (pricePerWeight2 <= 0) {
               
            
            }
        
           

            final float price1 = people * (pricePerWeight + pricePerWeight1 + pricePerWeight2);
            System.out.printf("Total: " + price1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hay innumerables formas de resolver este enunciado. Y no hay evidencia de que hayas probado alguna. Las preguntas sin código, errores y descripción de los problemas asociados, terminan cerradas. Por favor, revisa y amplía tu pregunta para que sea algo diferente a "tengo este enunciado"

Comment: Emmy dale, ya has preguntado antes acá, sabes como va esto XD

Comment: Arroz! Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? ese codigo no hace lo que necesitas?

Comment: Como continuo desde ahi? Gracias!

Comment: Lo que se necesita para que pueda ser una pregunta con una mejor calidad es que especifiques que problema tienes, no esta bien visto hacer un copy/paste de algo "medio hecho" y decir, terminarlo porfa. ¿Qué te falla, un bucle, una condición, te sale algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo resolvi!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fidegua {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    double precioFideos, precioGambas, precioCalamares;
    double costetotal;
    int personas;

            System.out.println("Para cuantas personas vas a cocinar hoy?");
            personas = sc.nextInt();
            
            System.out.print("Precio de los fideos [€/kg]: ");
            precioFideos = sc.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.print("Precio de las gambas [€/kg]: ");
            precioGambas = sc.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.print("Precio de los calamares [€/kg]: ");
            precioCalamares = sc.nextDouble();
            
            
         // calculamos ...
           double costeFideos = personas * precioFideos* 0.125;
           double costeGambas = personas * precioGambas* 0.05;
           double costeCalamares = personas * precioCalamares* 0.100;
           costetotal = costeFideos + costeGambas + costeCalamares;
           

    // resultado
            System.out.print("El coste total de la fidegua es ");
            System.out.println(costetotal);
            
            System.out.print("El precio por persona es ");
            System.out.println(costetotal/personas);
            
            System.out.println("Para " + personas + " personas necesitas " + (personas * 0.125)+  " kg de fideos");
            System.out.println( (personas * 0.05)+ " kg de gambas");
            System.out.println( (personas * 0.1) + " kg de calamares");
           
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Lo crees ?? o funciona ?? Si funciona explica tus errores en la respuesta ;)